# convert image to bytes & vice-versa via web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, image

- Am using VS2008 ASP web forms
- i have to make an image available to the end-user upon a file upload via web services
- the end-user will be able to display the image upon conversion of file bytes
- can someone direct me to a comprehensive yet simple example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on a physical file you can simply get the bytes with this:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: varbinary or blob for mssql, blog or text for mysql

Comment: if you want to stream image, its better to use HttpHandler than using WS, here a link that help you retrieve image data from the db http://dbtutorials.com/advanced/retrieving-binary-sql-vb.aspx

Comment: also if you are working on different type of images such as png, gif, jpg, bmp etc, it is also advisable to save the mime type in the db.

Comment: thank you :) did go through it. Here is the thing - i am using a databound detailsview to display data via WS, where it contains a field type of Image, therefore i cannot utilise any button to convert the binary data. In my scenario, how would you display the image within the detailsview?

Comment: as i have commented, its better to use HttpHandler for streaming image, in your case setup a HttpHandler that will stream a particular image, this handler should only stream 1 image so you need to pass a get parameter let us say an id, in your in your details view just use the url for example <img src="StreamImage.ashx?id=10" />